# package.json exports and multiple type declaration file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, package.json

I am trying build a TypeScript library and want to export using `exports` field in `package.json`.

From nodejs and webpack's documentation, I saw that `exports` is the recommended way to export modules.

https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#package-entry-points

https://webpack.js.org/guides/package-exports/

The old way is to use "main", "types" and "module".

How can I export type declaration using this method?
Should I keep using the "types" field? But what if I have multiple exports?

Here is a sample of exports I have

```json
"exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/A.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/A.js"
    },
    "./A": {
      "import": "./dist/A.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/A.js"
    },
    "./B": {
      "import": "./dist/B.mjs",
      "require": "./dist/B.js"
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like there is a solution, but I can't get it working.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#package-json-exports-imports-and-self-referencing

Answer (score 2):

The exports works with nodejs, but not supported by TypeScript. The way apollo library get this working is to create one `package.json` per exported path, like [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/main/packages/server/express4/package.json).

So in package.json, `exports` are still needed for compiled js code, and extra `package.json` is also required for TypeScript to find during development.

I had more detailed discussion [here](https://huakun.tech/docs/LearnWeb/Language/TypeScript/#exports-for-typescript). Sample code included.